# I'd like to display and editing a complex model in MVC.net 3 via Kendo UI components. What's the best practices for doing so?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, kendo-ui

I've got a complex ViewModel:
Ex:

```
public ExampleViewModel { 
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string description {get;set;}
    public List<ExampleViewModelSubItem> Items {get;set;}
    // multiple other collections and properties.
}
```

So I have no problems getting a KendoUI DataSource reading from an MVC route

```
public JsonObject GetExample() {
  return Json(getExample(), AllowJSONGet);
}
```

What I'm having issues with is how I should go about structuring the data source / pages.

If I had a simple ViewModel it would be easy, load the collection into a grid... Done.

But when I'm faced with a complex ViewModel (Object Graph) it's not quite so simple.

What I had in mind was to create a datasource that queries for the whole object and posts to the whole object.

And then widgets (grids for the lists) bound to each property of the Model.

In regular MVC.net without the client side components it would be fairly simple.

Using Kendo controls makes it seemingly more complex.

Thanks much.